# Aggregating features values based on name attribute and geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, geolocation, aggregation, duplication

In QGIS 3.28.1 I have a map with many points (it does not contain polygons and lines), and there are some duplicate points on top of each other in the same geographic location, and I would like to aggregate these points when they are in the exact same place + have the same name.
I tried doing an aggregate with the expression:

```
geom_to_wkb($geometry)
```

This aggregates all points that are in the same place regardless of their names.

I tried to use the expression:

```
geom_to_wkb($geometry) AND name
```

But that didn't work

Mu input:
[image: before]

My desired output:
[image: after]

Can you help me find the appropriate expression for the aggregate of points duplicated in the same place and with the same name?

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using logical operator [`AND`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#and), try the [`||`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat)-joint:

```
geom_to_wkt($geometry) || "name"
```

Comment: even easier: `$x || $y || "name"`

Comment: I do not think it is easier

Comment: it is shorter -